Analytic continuation gives a covering space (and not just a local homeomorphism)
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the space of germs of holomorphic functions defined on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, topologized in the usual way.  There is a natural map $p\colon \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ taking a germ of a holomorphic function defined on a neighborhood of a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ to $z_0$.  Let $M$ be a path component of $\mathcal{G}$.  One can view $M$ as being the "maximal analytic continuation" of any of its constituent germs.  It is basically trivial that the restriction of $p$ to $M$ is a local homeomorphism onto some open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$.  However, I have seen it asserted in many places that the map $p\colon M \rightarrow U$ is not just a local homeomorphism, but is actually a covering space.  Since in general the fibers of $p$ might be infinite, this does not come for free.
Is this true, and if so does anyone know a reference that proves it cleanly?  For instance, I can't quite find it in Forester's book, though he spends a lot of time constructing $\mathcal{G}$.

It is certainly not true.

@TomGoodwillie: That's kind of what I expected.  Do you know a counterexample?

There may be branched points where the derivative is zero.

@IanAgol: I think you're thinking of something slightly different, namely whether the holomorphic map itself is a covering space.  Essentially by definition the map I described is a local homeomorphism (note that it outputs a point in the domain of the function, not its range).

(note e.g. that there is a component $M$ that is the maximal analytic continuation of the entire function $f(z) = z^3$, and the map $p\colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a homeomorphism)

(another example: if you do this to a germ of $z^{1/3}$ around $1$, then you'll get the usual 3-fold cover from $M \cong \mathbb{C} \setminus 0$ to itself)

Okay, I see. $M$ is a Riemann surface with universal cover $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}^2$ or $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Let’s say it is $\mathbb{H}^2$, situated so it is the disk $|z-1|<1$. Under the map $z\to z^3$, this disk gets immersed. Take any holomorphic function with domain $\mathbb{H}^2$ to the complex plane, such as the $j$-invariant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant Now take $j \circ z^{1/3}$. $M$ is just $\mathbb{H}^2$, but its development into the plane will be via $z^3$ and hence will be immersed.

@IanAgol: If I'm understanding you correctly, $j \circ z^{1/3}$ cannot be analytically continued to any point where $j$ has a simple zero (and aren't all zeros of $j$ simple?).  So in that case, what you'll get for $M$ is a $3$-fold cover of $\mathbb{H}^2$ minus the zeros of $j$, and the map from $M$ to the complex plane is that 3-fold covering.

@Paul: No, I’m taking $\mathbb{H}^2$ to be $|z-1|<1$ (so I meant actually $j\circ (z-1)$, not $j$), so there won’t be a singularity or covering, it will be an immersion.

I was thinking of the same counterexample that Will Sawin describes in his answer.

Consider the map $f\colon z \mapsto z^3-z$. Then there is a path component $M$ of $\mathcal G$ consisting of germs of the inverse map to $f$. More precisely $M$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C \setminus \{ \pm \sqrt{ \frac{1}{3}}\}$, the domain of $f$ minus the points where its derivative vanishes, $M$ maps to $U = \mathbb C$ by $f$, and the germ at any point is the germ of a local inverse of $f$ at that point.
But $M \to \mathbb C$ is not a covering space since it has degree $3$ over most points but only degree $1$ over $ \pm - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$.
